# Advantages of a host as far as development

Tags: web-services, localhost, hosting, web-hosting

While working on a school project in my group today I suggested that we just host on our local machines for development. I got lots of confused looks and the group later suggested that we should instead find a host such as Amazon. I don't know much about hosting and databases, but is there something I'm missing here? I thought it will be easier to develop locally then host once we have something that is usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. That is the way to go. Else uploading the work every time to a remote host becomes a pain. Each developer should have fully working environment setup locally so that he/she can run and test the work quickly.